# How to size an SVG

Tags: svg

I am trying to create an SVG sprite.

I have set the SVG image to be 100px wide, 50px height, then offset the second by 50.

How can I set the size of the actual icon? Currently, the icon is huge and not 50px.

```
<svg version="1.1" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    width="100px" 
    height="50px">

    <defs>
        <g id="arrow">
            <path d="M378.135,227.256L206.224,55.354c-12.354-12.359-12.354-32.394,0-44.748c12.354-12.359,32.388-12.359,44.747,0
                L445.258,204.89c6.177,6.18,9.262,14.271,9.262,22.366c0,8.098-3.091,16.195-9.262,22.372L250.971,443.91
                c-12.359,12.365-32.394,12.365-44.747,0c-12.354-12.354-12.354-32.391,0-44.744L378.135,227.256z M9.265,399.166
                c-12.354,12.354-12.354,32.391,0,44.744c12.354,12.365,32.382,12.365,44.748,0l194.287-194.281
                c6.177-6.177,9.257-14.274,9.257-22.372c0-8.095-3.086-16.192-9.257-22.366L54.013,10.606c-12.365-12.359-32.394-12.359-44.748,0
                c-12.354,12.354-12.354,32.388,0,44.748L181.18,227.256L9.265,399.166z"/>
        </g>
    </defs>

    <use x="0" y="0" style="fill: #333" xlink:href="#arrow" />  
    <use x="50" y="0" style="fill: #999" xlink:href="#arrow" /> 

</svg>
```

This is what I see:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this? I just added `transform="scale(0.1)"` attribute to the `g` tag to make it 10x smaller

```html
<svg version="1.1" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    width="100px" 
    height="50px">

    <defs>
        <g id="arrow" transform="scale(0.1)">
            <path d="M378.135,227.256L206.224,55.354c-12.354-12.359-12.354-32.394,0-44.748c12.354-12.359,32.388-12.359,44.747,0
                L445.258,204.89c6.177,6.18,9.262,14.271,9.262,22.366c0,8.098-3.091,16.195-9.262,22.372L250.971,443.91
                c-12.359,12.365-32.394,12.365-44.747,0c-12.354-12.354-12.354-32.391,0-44.744L378.135,227.256z M9.265,399.166
                c-12.354,12.354-12.354,32.391,0,44.744c12.354,12.365,32.382,12.365,44.748,0l194.287-194.281
                c6.177-6.177,9.257-14.274,9.257-22.372c0-8.095-3.086-16.192-9.257-22.366L54.013,10.606c-12.365-12.359-32.394-12.359-44.748,0
                c-12.354,12.354-12.354,32.388,0,44.748L181.18,227.256L9.265,399.166z"/>
        </g>
    </defs>

    <use x="0" y="0" style="fill: #333" xlink:href="#arrow" />  
    <use x="50" y="0" style="fill: #999" xlink:href="#arrow" /> 

</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's spot on. Would you mind explaining what makes it 10x the size in the first place?

Comment: The coordinates in your `path` described the original oversized icon. I just tried various values until finding 0.1 that seems to fit...

Comment: This is not a correct answer. You shouldn't transform for scalign an svg.

Comment: @ccdavies, please accept Persijn's answer, which appears to be way better, i can't delete an accepted post.

Answer (score 3):

**DO NOT USE TRANSFORM FOR SCALING**

What you are missing is a defined viewBox. 
If you do not define a viewBox the viewBox is the same size as the height and width that you defined.

So when you draw a path and some of its point are above 370 then they will be outside its container. Since your defined size is 100 width by 50 height. Any point with values higher then the size will not be drawn.

when you define a viewBox you can change the size without affecting what is drawn or not.

This is the article i allways use when i forget how to properly scale svgs: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

```html
<svg version="1.1" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    width="100px" 
    height="50px"
    viewBox="0 0 500 500">

    <defs>
        <g id="arrow">
            <path d="M378.135,227.256L206.224,55.354c-12.354-12.359-12.354-32.394,0-44.748c12.354-12.359,32.388-12.359,44.747,0
                L445.258,204.89c6.177,6.18,9.262,14.271,9.262,22.366c0,8.098-3.091,16.195-9.262,22.372L250.971,443.91
                c-12.359,12.365-32.394,12.365-44.747,0c-12.354-12.354-12.354-32.391,0-44.744L378.135,227.256z M9.265,399.166
                c-12.354,12.354-12.354,32.391,0,44.744c12.354,12.365,32.382,12.365,44.748,0l194.287-194.281
                c6.177-6.177,9.257-14.274,9.257-22.372c0-8.095-3.086-16.192-9.257-22.366L54.013,10.606c-12.365-12.359-32.394-12.359-44.748,0
                c-12.354,12.354-12.354,32.388,0,44.748L181.18,227.256L9.265,399.166z"/>
        </g>
    </defs>

    <use x="0" y="0" style="fill: #333" xlink:href="#arrow" />  
    <use x="50" y="0" style="fill: #999" xlink:href="#arrow" /> 

</svg>
```